# Links request. What tools that can completely develop web applications with visual (gui-interface) approach? Not CMS

Tags: html, css, ajax

Are there similar tools that works like [Softwell Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softwell_Maker)?

**Softwell maker:**
The Softwell Maker is an environment for developing corporate Rich Internet Application (HTML + CSS + AJAX). The focus of this tool is high productivity in software development, better interaction between the developers and their customers in the development process, and a technological independence of the developed application. **Using this software it is possible to develop web applications on a 100% visual approach, without writing lines of code.** To realize this, Softwell Maker designer uses visual forms and reports (WYSIWYG), business rules, and visually representing other actions using flowcharts.

Probably will not attend all demand, but I would like keep in mind for soon use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you want is [Adobe Bridge](http://www.adobe.com/products/bridge.html) or [Adobe Edge](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/).

I'm not sure about the AJAX capabilities, but it does allow to make cool stuff.

Comment: I typically use bridge for file management and minor meta changes. I don't believe it has anywhere near the capabilities described in OP's post. Thanks for the Edge link though, pretty neat.

Comment: Looks like this tools you described didn't match what I need (a tool that can be used to develop a full web application without nothing external). Am I correct?

Comment: Edge could help you to some extent. It just depends on what you call "full web application".

Answer (score 0):

In the end it will be a bad idea. Everything what comes out of a "visual wonder creator" will be in the end nothing more than a amateur app.
If you want to create a professional app, you can perhaps use the visual creator for some basic elements.
But in my opinion you forget at best completely the visual part of the ide an make it completely by hand. Only then you can be sure that you exactly get what you need and want.

Comment: I would say I agree with this, but, maybe is interesting if you need simple apps and need it for yesterday. I saw the tool video tutorial and I liked it, looks good. Several features, but I think we have another conpetitors and I would like to know them and see its tools.